# How to check GPU Temp / Fan Speed by Node JS

Tags: node.js, gpu

I can not find anything about it. I found the video card information. I need to check GPU Temp and Fan Speed. What do I need to use if I want to use the NodeJS ?

Comment: I guess you can just use the core `OS` module?

Comment: @FelixFong Currently the OS module does not provide any information about the fan and the temp, I'm here looking for the same information.